# How i can ensure certificate(myAppCertificate.crt) i am importing to cacert already exists in cacert file or not?.

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

How i can ensure certificate(myAppCertificate.crt) i am importing  to cacert already exists in cacert file or not?. 
For information i am importing the certificate with

keytool -import -alias myAppca -file myAppCertificate.crt -keystore cacerts -v

For testing purpose i tried to add the already existing certficate  again in cacert file, but it did not give me any exception/warning
that certificate already exist. **Is there a way i can confirm whether certificate alreay exist or not before actually importing this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `keytool -list -keystore cacerts`, you'll get the list of all the certificates with their fingerprints. (If you use keytool from Java 6, you'll see MD5 fingerprints, if you use the version from Java 7, you'll get SHA-1 fingerprints, better.)

If you use `keytool -printcert -file myAppCertificate.crt`, you should see the certificate fingerprints (including MD5 and SHA-1).

If the value you get from that certificate is in the list, your certificate is already in the keystore.

(For more details on what fingerprints are, see [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14330/2435).)

Comment: Hi Bruno, actually the certificate i am trying to import is the chain of certificate A---->B---->C(myCertificate). As per my understanding
if the output of commanbd you mentioned , contains the fingrerprint of any of the certificates(A,B or C), then i do not need to import
the certificate.RIGHT? Another point is , i can see the fingerprint of C in webbrowser to cross verify it in the output of command.
But where can i see the fingerprint of certificates  A and B (which are above in hierarchy  than C)?

Comment: Typically, you only need to import the top of the chain (A) in `cacerts` (unless you only want to trust a subtree). To see each cert's finger print, split your crt file into sub-files (with begin/end delimiters) or use a browser that can display the fingerprint for intermediate certs (Chrome and probably IE can do this on windows, they call it the 'thumbprint' in the cert details.)

Comment: One more thing is that command  "keytool -import -alias myAppca -file myAppCertificate.crt -keystore cacerts -v" does import of lowest certificate in hiererchy.For example in my case it did import of C instead of A.Ideally it should import the certificate at the top of hierrachy Is n't it? Also IE and mozilla firefox show the different certification path. Ideally they should show same. To me certification path of IE looks correct not firefox. Any Inputs?

Comment: `keytool -import` should import the first cert if finds in the file (since it's just a text file with multiple BEGIN/END blocks). It's common to put the chain with the issuer cert following the signed cert (higher authority last), since that's how some tools are configured. It's possible to have different certification paths, since some CAs sometimes renew their certs progressively.

Comment: As you said "It's possible to have different certification paths, since some CAs sometimes renew their certs progressively". Agreed that some CAs sometimes renew their certs,  but even if they do that , i should see same certification path in both the browser i.e IE and firefox becoz i am hitting them at almost same time. How come its dependent on browser?

Comment: I'm talking about the CAs, not the server's certificate. What you're hitting at the same time is the server cert. Your CAs are pre-installed with the latest updates that was installed with your OS or browser. IE uses Windows's CAs, where Firefox uses its own.

Comment: Start getting the point. Still would like to clarify it with this scenario. Say when i installed the windows it came with the pack where CA2 authorized CA3. so path is CA2-->CA3. Now when i hit the application,i get the server certificate as CA2--->mySiteCertificate. So IE will show the certificate path as CA2-->CA3--->mySiteCertificate. Now consider the same scenario with Firefox. when i installed the firefox,CA1 additionaly authorize the CA2. So in firefox, my revised server certificate will show the certificate path as CA1-->CA2-->CA3--->mySiteCertificate. RIGHT?

Comment: (You probably meant "CA3--->mySiteCertificate"). Yes, more or less. In this case, CA2 might be self-signed (issuer=subject) in IE, but not in FF (where it's issued by CA1). You can have cross-signing too.

Comment: is it possible to determine somewhere in browser what is the exact certificate that server sent , not the certificate path?For example in above scenario, if server sent  certificate CA3--->mySiteCertificate and IE  already had CA2--->CA3 . I see the certification path  as CA2-->CA3--->mySiteCertificate. Can i see somewhere in IE/any other browser what is the exact certificate path server sent which is CA3--->mySiteCertificate in this case not CA2-->CA3--->mySiteCertificate. I really appreciate your patience for answering all the queries. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the keytool **list** option to view all the certs in a keystore:
    keytool -list -v -keystore keystorefile